# Centos/RHEL 7: OpenSSL update not available

Tags: openssl

I have  openssl 1.0.1e installed but its seems to be buggy based on [this](https://www.openssl.org/news/secadv/20151203.txt)
But when I list out the updates for the system it doesn't list out 1.0.1q as suggested on above link.

Any idea how to install through yum or by compiling?

```
Installed Packages
openssl.x86_64                                                                1:1.0.1e-51.el7_2.2                                                                 @updates
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to upgrade or compile anything.

The document you reference state that you should update from 1.0.1 to 1.0.1q because of CVE-2015-3194, CVE-2015-3195 and CVE-2105-3196. However, if you run:

```
rpm -q --changelog openssl | grep CVE-2015-319
```

you should get:

```
- fix CVE-2015-3194 - certificate verify crash with missing PSS parameter
- fix CVE-2015-3195 - X509_ATTRIBUTE memory leak
- fix CVE-2015-3196 - race condition when handling PSK identity hint
```

which means that these fixed have been retrospectively applied to your version of openSSL.

Distros don't update their versions on every time upstream release, as these releases are relatively new and untested. Instead they cherry-pick the patches that they will apply.  Usually, this means security patches or regression fixes only.

Comment: Beat me to it... FWIW, here's the [pertinent Centos-announce post](https://lists.centos.org/pipermail/centos-announce/2015-December/021519.html) and [Redhat annoucement](https://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2015-2617.html)

Comment: rpm -q --changelog openssl | grep CVE-2015-319  

Ouput of this is nothing on my server so i guess i donot have updated version ?? Then how do i update

Comment: `sudo yum update openssl` should do it.

Comment: "No Packages marked for Update"

Comment: `rpm -q openssl` on my CentOS 7.1 shows: `openssl-1.0.1e-51.el7_2.2.x86_64`.  Check yours.  If it's not the same, then you need to investigate why your system isn't updating. Have a look around this site for suggestions and if you get stuck, post a new question - it keeps things tidy on here :-)

Comment: its openssl-1.0.1e-42.el6.x86_64.

Comment: `el6` - that doesn't look like CentOS/RHEL 7 to me as I believe it should say `el7` for those.  Check `/etc/centos-release` or `/etc/redhat-release` to confirm what you're actually running.  I've just found I'm running 7.2, not 7.1 as I stated in my previous comment :-o

Comment: @pkm: as I linked above, -42 incorporates redhat erratum CESA/RHSA-2015-2617 which fixes CVE-2015-3194, -3195, -3196.

Answer (score 0):

`yum update openssl` issue, I was getting this following error while trying to update openssl:

> Loaded plugins: product-id, refresh-packagekit, rhnplugin, security, subscription-manager
>
> There was an error communicating with RHN. RHN Satellite or RHN Classic support will be disabled. Error communicating with server.
>
> The message was:
>
> Error Class Code: 6001
>
> Error Class Info: RHN is in the process of being decommissioned and systems are no longer able to receive updates or make use of any RHN services. Please see https://access.redhat.com/articles/2979901 for more info.
>
> Setting up Update Process
>
> Could not retrieve mirrorlist https://mirrors.iuscommunity.org/mirrorlist?repo=ius-el6&arch=x86_64&protocol=http
>
> error was 14: Peer cert cannot be verified or peer cert invalid
>
> Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: ius. Please verify its path and try again.

I got the solution for error code 6001. Here is the summery which resolved that issue:

```
mv /etc/yum.repos.d/* /tmp/
rm -rf /var/cache/yum/*
yum clean all
yum repolist
yum update openssl
yum list installed openssl
```